# difference between exit and return after vfork() call

Tags: c, posix, fork, multiprocessing

I have a program with undefined behavior ( vfork() is used inappropriately ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    pid_t pid;
    printf("___________befor fork______________.\n");
    if((pid=vfork()) < 0)
        perror("fork");
    else if(pid > 0)
        printf("parent\n");
    else
        printf("child\n");

    printf("pid: %d, ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    //exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `exit(0)` function instead return - output is:

```
___________befor fork______________.
child
pid: 4370, ppid: 4369
parent
pid: 4369, ppid: 2924
```

If I use `return 0` - I get infinite output like this:

```
___________befor fork______________.
child
pid: 4455, ppid: 4454
parent
pid: 4454, ppid: 2924
___________befor fork______________.
child
pid: 4456, ppid: 4454
parent
pid: 4454, ppid: 2924
___________befor fork______________.
child
pid: 4457, ppid: 4454
parent
pid: 4454, ppid: 2924
    and so on ...
```

I know that you can not use `return` in the child after the `vfork()` function.
But I don't understand why the parent does not end after `return` call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not valid to return from the function in the child, because with `vfork()` both the parent and child share the same stack and returning in the child will mess up the stack frame for the parent.  Usually the call to `main()` (in the start function) is followed by a call to `exit()` or similar, so that call to `exit()` in the child will overwrite the same stack space that the call to `main()` was using (and is still using in the parent).  So when the child does exit, the parent will return from `vfork()` but the return address on the stack will likely be clobbered so it could return to any address or do anything at all.

Also, in the child, if you do not exec you should call `_exit()` rather than `exit()`.  `exit()` will flush the stdio output buffers but those same buffers are being managed by the parent, whereas `_exit()` will just end the process.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything is OK.  If you don't follow the rules and you do invoke undefined behaviour, anything may happen.  Be grateful that it did not reformat the disk on your machine, or recursively remove everything under your home directory; either is acceptable behaviour when you invoke undefined behaviour.  The classic term is ['Nasal Demons'](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), meaning it might make demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: @nick: If you call exit() from within main(), an additional stack frame is added to the top of the stack so main's stack frame is not clobbered: start->main->exit.  If you return from main and then start calls exit(), the stack frames will be: start->exit, so exit's frame will overwrite the memory that was used for main's stack frame, which is still in use in the parent.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes of course.  The OP stated in his question that he knows it is undefined behavior.  There is nothing wrong with trying to understand why.  There would be little progress if people didn't question the rules every now and then or understand why they exist.

Answer (score 3):

By returning in your child process you are causing undefined behavior, so anything can really happen.

It looks like you parent process works fine, but the child process, instead of exiting, restarts `main` function.

Answer (score 3):

you can see the definition of vfork in the kernel.org : http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vfork.2.html . it is a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The current POSIX standard does not support `vfork()` at all.
In the old (1997-ish) POSIX standard, the page for [`vfork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/vfork.html) said:

> The `vfork()` function has the same effect as `fork()`, except that the behaviour is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec` family of functions.

Your code is not calling either an `exec` family function or `_exit()`, so you invoke undefined behaviour, and anything that happens is legitimate.

You've just demonstrated why it is not usually sensible to use `vfork()`.  IMNSHO, it is in the same camp as `gets()`; I know it exists but I would never use it voluntarily, and I'd be perfectly happy for the implementations to be:

```
pid_t vfork(void) { abort(); }
char *gets(char *buffer) { abort(); }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be used in portable programs, but if you are developing for a platform where fork() is inefficient then it can be a good way to gain efficiency if you are using fork() in certain limited ways.  Just make sure that you are not violating the limitations of vfork() as documented by your particular platform.  On some kinds of hardware it is just not possible to implement the general fork() functionality in an efficient manner.