# in vfork child are created repeatedly

Tags: c, child-process, vfork

Anyone can explain the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
  int a=1;
  int pid;
  if((pid = vfork()) == 0)
  {
    printf("This is child . %d\n", getpid() );
    a=2;
  }
  else 
  {
    printf("%d\t%d\n",getpid(),a);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

In the above code, child processes are created repeatedly.  Can anyone please help me understand the logic?

Comment: when your creating a child process using vfork() function, you must use the exit() function or any one of execl() function to terminate the process.

Comment: In a `vfork`-ed child, doing anything else than `exec*` or `_exit` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676619/difference-between-exit-and-return-after-vfork-call  Verify this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the manual page for `vfork`. Especially the part where it tells you what you are allowed to do in the child. You are not allowed to call `getpid` in the child. You are not allowed to call `printf` in the child. You are not allowed to set the variable `a`. You are not allowed to return from the function that called `vfork` in the child. You did all those things therefore the code does something unexpected. Unfortunately for you the unexpected thing isn't crashing.

You may only call `_exit` or one of the `exec*` functions in a `vfork`:ed child. Nothing else.

The `vfork` system call is a optimization hack from the days when `fork` was very expensive. So what it does it to suspend the parent process and use the parents address space in the child (this may or may not be true depending on operating system) until the child calls `exec*` or `_exit`. Any memory write that the child does will overwrite memory in the parent process. Calling functions will overwrite memory in ways that the parent process doesn't expect. Returning from the function that called `vfork` will definitely overwrite state that the parent expects to be intact (like the return addresses and saved stack pointers). Calling `printf` will overwrite stdio buffers that the parent doesn't expect to be overwritten, etc.

It could probably be reasoned why in your case the parent calls itself again after the child exits, after all computers are quite deterministic. If you analyze the crt code that calls main, the various atexit handlers in libc and other cleanup you could probably figure out exactly what happens to write what at the right place on the stack that makes the parent confused and return to the wrong place after the syscall returns. Disassemble the code and go for it. Or you could just search this site for the dozens of other questions about `vfork` and notice that they all follow the same theme: "Why does vfork do *something unexpected* when I do something the documentation tells me not to do?". It does it because it's undefined behavior and the way undefined behavior behaves is undefined. In your case overwriting memory that the parent didn't expect to have overwritten happened to make the parent call itself again. In other cases I've seen it made printf print twice. In other cases nothing bad happened. In other cases the program crashed.

Comment: can you explain me why we can't use the printf and getpid function in a child process which is created by vfork call.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Because the manual said so. Everything else is undefined behavior. It's undefined behavior because `vfork` does horrible things to the address space of the parent process. Anything you do outside of what the documentation allows you to do can and probably will overwrite the stack and other memory of the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. When we are using the exit or exec functions in a child that time it is working good. That time this mistake is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

You should terminate the child process using the exit() or exec. otherwise the child 
termination status will not reach to the parent. so, the child process is in zombie state.

Comment: what are you trying to say.. zombie means i didn't understand

Comment: You are not allowed to call `exit` in the child process. And it has nothing to do with zombies.

Comment: @Art - whenever you want to terminate process.using the exit() function. it will terminate the process properly. where you read the  statement. Have you experimented with exit() function

Comment: @EsakkiThangam The POSIX standard and most if not all operating systems manual pages say that you're only allowed to use `_exit` in a vforked child. For a good reason, because `_exit` is very different from `exit`. I've not only experimented with the `exit` function, I've worked on big parts of it in an operating system. `exit` is unsafe in a vforked child because it will do things in the address space of the parent that the parent doesn't expect (like close stdio streams, run atexit handlers, etc.).