# call vfork() in function, confused about the result

Tags: c, unix, fork, vfork

This is an exercise in "APUE" chapter 8(exercise 8.2, 2th edtion). The all discription is:

> Recall the typical arrangement of memory in Figure 7.6. Because the stack frames
>   corresponding to each function call are usually stored in the stack, and because after a
>   vfork the child runs in the address space of the parent, what happens if the call to vfork
>   is from a function other than main and the child does a return from this function after the
>   vfork? Write a test program to verify this, and draw a picture of what’s happening.

In my program:

```
static void f1(void), f2(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("main address: %d\n", main);
    f1();
    f2();
    _exit(0);
}

static void f1(void) {
    printf("f1 address: %d\n", f1);
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = vfork()) < 0)
        err_sys("vfork error");
}

static void f2(void) {
    printf("f2 address: %d\n", f2);
    char buf[1000];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); ++i)
        buf[i] = 0;
}
```

I run the program, the output is:

```
main address: 4196560
f1 address: 4196604
f2 address: 4196663
f1 address: 4196604
[1]    12929 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

I am confused about the output.

1. print `f1 address: xxx`, we call vfork(), the child process runs first.
2. print `f2 address: xxx`, then child process calls _exit(0).
3. main progress return from f1(), the stack frame of f1 was changed by f2, it may result segmentation fault.

But why print `f1 address: 4196604` twice and why the address of f1 and f2 are not same?

Comment: `buf` is not initialized so `strlen(buf)` is undefined behaviour (and probably the cause of the segfault). Was that intentional?

Comment: is vfork an alias for fork() on your platform?

Comment: @rici sizeof(buf) is the same

Comment: It is not even similar. strlen counts bytes until it finds the 0.

Comment: @rici you are right, I have changed the strlen() by using sizeof().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the statck frame of f1 was changed by f2".

The code in `f2()` is likely to segmentation fault in any case, regardless of `vfork()`. `buf` is uninitialized. There's no reason to believe it contains a null-terminated string. Therefore, the call to `strlen()` could read off the end of the buffer.

In any case, I'm not sure what you expect the loop to do. In the first iteration, `i` is 0. If the call to `strlen()` does not segfault, then the loop body stores 0 in `buf[0]`. Therefore, on the next iteration of the loop, `strlen(buf)` will be 0, `i` will be 1 (which is not less than 0), so the loop will terminate.

The second print of `f1 address: 4196604` is when the parent process continues after the `vfork()`-ed subprocess exits. The parent process continues and calls `f1()` which prints that.

The numbers that you print are the addresses of `f1` and `f2` themselves. Why would you expect the address of `f1` to be the same as the address of `f2`? They are not, so they print different addresses.

On the other hand, the address of `f1` is the same in the parent process and the subprocess, since the subprocess shares the parent's address space. So, the same address is printed for `f1` both times.

Comment: I change strlen() with sizeof(). The code is an exercise of "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environmnet".

Comment: And, after making that change, does it still segmentation fault?

Comment: I update the question, and you can have a look. After changing, it does still segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

According to `vfork` [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html), you should not return from current function.

> vfork() differs from fork(2) in that the calling thread is suspended
>          until the child terminates (either normally, by calling _exit(2), or
>          abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), or it makes a call to
>          execve(2).  Until that point, the child shares all memory with its
>          parent, including the stack.  **The child must not return from the
>          current function or call exit(3), but may call _exit(2)**.

Also, please note that:

> vfork() is a special case of clone(2).  It is **used to create new
>          processes without copying the page tables of the parent process**.  It
>          may be useful in performance-sensitive applications where a child is
>          created which then immediately issues an execve(2).

Since `vfork` does not copy the page tables from the parent, it makes a lot of sense not to return from current function. When the child exits it will mess up the stack frame from the parent.

You can also view the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676619/difference-between-exit-and-return-after-vfork-call)